# Python: executing a long-running process with subprocess.Popen, killing it, and accessing to its output

Tags: python, multithreading, subprocess

I'm trying to run a "long-running" process as root (because I have to), in a thread, in python, then kill it, and then access to its output.

The process in question is "babeld", and when I just launch it in a terminal, it outputs text on stdout. Yet, when I run the following code, I do not have any access to stderr or stdout:

```
% ./example.py                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
Waiting for output
Pgid: 13445, pid: 13445
Stopping task
Permission Error!
Calling sudo kill 13445
B
None
None
End
```

The code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import subprocess
import threading
import time
import os

def main():
    task = TaskManager()
    task.launch()
    time.sleep(2)
    task.stop()

    print(task.stdout)
    print(task.stderr)


class TaskManager(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.start_event = threading.Event()
        self.stderr = None
        self.stdout = None
        self.pgid = None
        self.task = None
        self.start()


    def run(self):
        self.start_event.wait()
        self.task = subprocess.Popen(["sudo", "babeld", "-d", "2", "wlp2s0"],
                                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                     stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                                     preexec_fn=os.setsid)
        self.pgid = os.getpgid(self.task.pid)
        print("Waiting for output")
        self.stdout, self.stderr = self.task.communicate()
        print("End")

    def launch(self):
        self.start_event.set()

    def stop(self):
        print("Pgid: %s, pid: %s" % (self.pgid, self.task.pid))
        try:
            print("Stopping task")
            self.task.terminate()
        except PermissionError:
            print("Permission Error!")
            print("Calling sudo kill %d" % self.pgid)
            subprocess.check_call(["sudo", "kill", str(self.pgid)])
            print("B")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

How to properly kill processes running as root, while having access to their stderr and stdout?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The recipe is simple: do not use `communicate`. You may replace your `self.stdout` and `self.stderr` class attributes with the following getters:

```
@property
def stdout(self):
    return self.task.stdout.read()

@property
def stderr(self):
    return self.task.stderr.read()
```

BTW, this approach gives you an opportunity to reject threading usage in your code. Example:

```
# !/usr/bin/env python3

import subprocess
import time
import os


def main():
    task = TaskManager()
    task.launch()
    time.sleep(2)
    task.stop()

    print(task.stdout)
    print(task.stderr)


class TaskManager:
    def __init__(self):
        self.pgid = None
        self.task = None

    @property
    def stdout(self):
        return self.task.stdout.read()

    @property
    def stderr(self):
        return self.task.stderr.read()

    def launch(self):
        self.task = subprocess.Popen(["sudo", "babeld", "-d", "2", "wlp2s0"],
                                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                     stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                                     preexec_fn=os.setsid)
        self.pgid = os.getpgid(self.task.pid)
        print("Waiting for output")

    def stop(self):
        print("Pgid: %s, pid: %s" % (self.pgid, self.task.pid))
        try:
            print("Stopping task")
            self.task.terminate()
        except PermissionError:
            print("Permission Error!")
            print("Calling sudo kill %d" % self.pgid)
            subprocess.check_call(["sudo", "kill", str(self.pgid)])
            print("B")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your answer, it seems it works! I want to be sure I understand: what was the problem with communicate?

Comment: The problem was in threading: you accessed the `stdout` and `stderr` properties in  one thread, and updated them in the second. The desired result could be reached in this manner, using locks, but this increases the overall complexity and, as you see, pretty much redundant.

Comment: Still you can try your initial solution with a short `sleep` after `task.stop()` to ensure  the problem is in threading and a `communicate` call, locking one of the threads and lately settind the `stdout` and `stderr` attributes